# Error "telephonyService cannot be resolved" for `telephonyService.answerRingingCall();` method call

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am attempting to create an application that will automatically answer calls when a checkbox is checked. I have added ITelephony.aidl to com.android.internal.telephony and have followed information on the web, but I can't seem to get it going, it wont let me use the `answerRingingCall();` method. error  I am  getting "telephonyService cannot be resolved" for `telephonyService.answerRingingCall();`

Any suggestions?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class AnswerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        CheckBox AnswerCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.answerCheck); 

        AnswerCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
            boolean isChecked) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 

                telephonyService.answerRingingCall();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Calls will be answered", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Calls will NOT be answered", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            } 

            } 
            }); 

            } 

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `telephonyService.answerRingingCall();` method in `PhoneStateListener`

```
  // Create a new PhoneStateListener
  listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

          break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

          break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
          // Ringing.. answer now
          telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
          break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. but, I am still getting "telephonyService cannot be resolved"  for telephonyService.answerRingingCall();

Comment: Why isnt this in your question. You should have put this error there..In fact, this error should be the title of your post

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the `answerPhoneAidl` method of the following link:
https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java